# How to fix Angular Error: NG0100 before ngOnChange is called

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

There are 2 child-components (bar/edit) under app-component, edit component will emit an `@output number` from `ngOnChanges` function to the app component . Which the app component will stored it like below.

app.component.ts

```
editCount:number=0;
editCountReceiver(data:number){
  this.editCount=data;
  console.log("app component receieved = "+this.editCount);
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-edit (send_edit_count)="editCountReceiver($event)"></app-edit>
```

The bar component will then get the number from the app component by using `@input` like below .

app.component.html

```
<app-search-bar [total_edit]="editCount"">
```

bar.component.typescript

```
@Input() total_edit: number  ;
```

And then the error appeared.
"ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0'. Current value: '1'.. "

One line of code is included in the error message, as shown below.

```
<app-search-bar [total_edit]="editCount"">
```

I was trying to fix this issue for couple of hours already and I have found out it has to do with the hook thing. So I decided to `console.log` almost all hooks for further investigation. The result is quite long so I just capture few lines that I think might be helpful.

[image]

Supposedly, since the value is bind with `@input`. I expect the `ngOnChanges` is called right after app component receive number and update bar component `@input` number accordingly.

But no, an error message is appeared before the `ngOnChanges` called. I presume it's because the `@input` data is updated slower than the `afterViewChecked` hook. So please, how can I fix this issue and make sure @input update is detected and applies before the `afterViewChecked` hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe, if you need to be notified, it's probably with a Subject that you must subscribe. Since I don't have all the code in your question, it's hard to give you a good answer.

In that case, one component can emit the value with the `Subject` by calling `next` and the component that need to be notified can `Subcribe` to the same `Subject`.

After some research, you can use a setter on the `Input`, but in this case, you will run after some problems if the value is passed by reference. (ex. An array, or an object).

In that case, something like this can work:

```
private editCountField: number;
get countField(): number{
    return this.editCountField;
}
@Input() set countField(newCountField: number) {
    this.editCountField = newCountField;
    this.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: You mean `Observable` and `subscribe()` ? Great suggestion. I remember in last project I used like 20 `Observable` , works way easier than `@input` / `@output` But is there really no other way to just use `@input` / `@ output` to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of tearing my hair out and searching the most obscure recesses of the internet, I have something to add, that none of the other forums mention, including SO.

I am adding this solution, because I see you are using an *@Output* emitter.

If you have run out of ideas and are still getting:

```
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
```

Please check your *@Output* reference methods.
What do I mean by reference method?
Here is the pattern:

```
// child-component.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output() someOutput = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    ngOnInit() {
        this.someOutput.emit(true);
    }
}

// parent-component.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    someOutput(input: boolean): void {
        setTimeout( () => {
          this.input = input;
          // do stuff
        });
    }
}

// parent-component.component.html

<app-child
  (someOutput)="someOutput($event)">
</app-child>
```

The key here is to add:

```
setTimeout( () => {
}
```

Inside your output reference method.

All of the other solutions seem to talk exclusively about the **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError** error, in relation to the *@Input* binding, but the *@Output* emitter, is just as vulnerable to this issue.

I am going to add this solution to as many relevant forum threads, as possible, because very little has been written about this notorious error, when using the *@Output* emitter. I apologize, in advance, if this answer isn't 100% relevant, to this question, however if this solution helps, at least one person, then I feel it will have been a worthwhile task.